# A simple OCaml program

Tags: ocaml

I want to learn a bit of OCaml, just to get a taste of a programming language other than C++ and Java. I will be very greatful if you help me with the following program: basically the user inputs a positive integer. The sum of all integers from N to 0 is printed.

Obviously you create an integer `N`, let the user enter its value. Create a variable `sum` of type `int`. Have a `for` loop which will add `N` to `sum` and then decrement `N`'s value by one. The loop will run while `N` is greater than 1. I have no idea how to do this in OCaml's syntax though.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you describe your algorithm is how you would typically implement it in C++ or in Java. You can write it the same way in OCaml, but the idiomatic way would be a recursive function that does not mutate variables, as follows:

```
let rec print_sum acc n =
  if n <= 0
  then Printf.printf "Sum: %d\n" acc
  else print_sum (acc + n) (n - 1)
```

Invoke with: `print_sum 0 11 ;;`

To write a recursive function:

1. First think of the base case when it is not necessary to recurse. This will save you from forgetting it (here, it's the case `n <= 0`)
2. The general case: how can you get one step closer to the base case already written? Here it's by invoking the function with `n-1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! This was the answer I needed!

Comment: Here's a solution with less bloat. let print_sum n = print_int (n*(n+1)/2)